# Restore HDD after corruption

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bsod

I apologize for the vague title, I'll change it as soon as someone can help me at least figure out the cause.

I was syncing a large folder, that still should've left me with enough free space, but mid-download Windows notified me that I'm running out of space on C. Before I could delete or uninstall anything, the laptop froze for a moment and I saw a Win10 BSOD for the first time (Invalid store exception). Apparently, Windows was downloading an update, that filled up my hard drive.

After a series of failed boots, Windows started automatic repair, updated successfully, and now I can boot into Windows, but there are some Major issues.

1. Start Menu, Notifications Pane, and Wifi connections list won't show up. Clicking on the Wifi icon and "Show available networks" in Settings do nothing.
2. The amount of free space on drive C rapidly keeps decreasing, so even though I'm able to boot, after a while free space reaches 0 and I get the same BSOD.

I've checked my hard drive with windows' own tool and a few third-party tools. No errors.

I downloaded the Wifi driver from my laptop's website and reinstalled it. No change. Wifi works just fine with every boot USB I've tried, the problem is only in Windows.

I've checked my laptop with Malwarebytes and Kasperky boot disk, and, even though the found and deleted something, neither of the issues are resolved.

Yes, I did consider reinstalling afresh, but for that I would at least need network access to backup files.

Does this sound familiar to anybody, any solutions?!

---Update---
After a few more boots, this is all I see now. The laptop is branded, but this is where the Windows logo usually is

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to process the 3-6GB that is the 1803 update. Boot into Windows, clear as much as you can off the drive, and then let the update happen. After it's done clear the drive using [Disk clean-up in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026616/windows-10-disk-cleanup) and clear the old version of Windows to free up space again. Then carry on as you were.

Comment: @Mokubai The update DID take place. That's why I'm sure there should be nothing else downloading in the background. I cleaned with CCleaner after the update. Currently I have a bootdisk running doing more checks. Next time I boot I'll try Disk Cleanup, not sure if it'll make a world of difference, though.

Comment: Don't use CCleaner for this, use the built-in Disk Cleanup, this one can remove the cached Windows Update files.

Comment: @music2myear I assume you're the one who changed the title. So, we're sure this is HDD corruption? Also, last time it did boot, I DID run Disk Cleanup, but it didn't do anything at all. Now I have a WinPE boot usb. Can I use that to fix the issue. At this time, I just need to boot at least once to backup some things that require a program running, such as firefox profile data. Then I can just detach the HDD, copy the files to my desktop and do a clean install on the laptop.

Comment: Don't assume...

Comment: Also, "something's wrong with my laptop" is super vague title that tells us nothing, and so the edit that was made was a good one based on reasonable inferences drawn from the content of your question.

Comment: @JakeGould If we're sure this won't be helpful to anyone else, feel free to delete this. I no longer seek to figure out the cause. I just wanna back things up as soon as possible, and install a fresh copy.

Comment: We're not worried about it helping others. We're mostly concerned about the likelihood that we'll be able to get you an answer. Frankly, at this point, I'd be doing a repair install, and if that doesn't work, a clean install. Windows 10 has some good repair and recovery capabilities, but if that's all you're getting on your screen, it appears the damage to the system is pretty severe, and the effort to repair would be pretty high.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks. But that's all it is, right? Just the system, this does not indicate that the HDD itself is damaged. So, a good old format should make things right?

Comment: OK. thanks for the help, guys. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: 1) The drive may be OK, but based on the symptoms, even with the tests you've run, would make me distrust it. Especially the available space decreasing after the issue began. 2) Sticking a Windows 10 install disk/drive should offer to try to repair things. 3) If you've got super important data, you need to focus on getting that recovered to somewhere else before you reinstall Windows because more work on the drive will increase potential damage to the data and the reinstall WILL write over the data.

Comment: This highlights one of the difficulties of a QA website: You're our eyes and hands, and we're the brains. More or less. If myself or another tech pro were on-site we'd be observing a bunch of things that would expand our diagnosis dictionary and lead us towards a possible viable solution other than "nuke it from orbit". But you can only communicate what you have observed so far, and we don't see enough data in the information yet conveyed to point us in a strong direction, it is time and effort prohibitive to delve further in this context. A local expert may be a good resource now.